# Overriding @XmlTransient behavior using external mapping file in Moxy

Tags: jaxb2, moxy

Why can't I override the "type" property to be non-transient using external mapping as shown below? When I serialize, I doesn't see the "type" element.

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    private String type;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    //other properties
}
```

I specified "type" using "xml-attribute" hoping that this will take precedence over the annotation but it isn't working.

```
<java-type name="PhoneNumber">
         <java-attributes>
            <xml-attribute java-attribute="type" />
            <xml-value java-attribute="number" />
         </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have hit a bug.  You can track our progress on this issue using the link below:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/387436

**WORKAROUND**

You could specify that field access should be used for the `PhoneNumber` class.

```
    <java-type name="PhoneNumber" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-attribute java-attribute="type" />
            <xml-value java-attribute="number"/>
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
```

**FULL EXAMPLE**

**PhoneNumber**

```
package forum11991936;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

public class PhoneNumber {
    private String type;
    private String number;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

**oxm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum11991936">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="PhoneNumber" xml-accessor-type="FIELD">
            <xml-root-element name="phone-number"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="type" />
                <xml-value java-attribute="number"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**jaxb.properties**

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

```
package forum11991936;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum11991936/oxm.xml");
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {PhoneNumber.class}, properties);

        PhoneNumber pn = new PhoneNumber();
        pn.setType("cell");
        pn.setNumber("555-1111");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(pn, System.out);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phone-number type="cell">555-1111</phone-number>
```

Comment: Thx. Could you also pls look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993667/reusable-complextype-and-xml-registry-xml-element-decl-usage. I am not sure even how to approach this issue.