# Reusable complexType, and xml-registry, xml-element-decl usage

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, moxy

I've the below **TimePeriodType**

```
<xs:simpleType name="UnitOfTimePeriodType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="Months"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Days"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Years"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="TimePeriodType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Length" type="digit1-3"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="unitOfLength" type="UnitOfTimePeriodType" use="optional" default="Months"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

which gets used in multiple types as shown below

```
<xs:complexType name="USAddressType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AddressType">
            <xs:sequence>                   
                <xs:element name="LengthAtAddress" type="TimePeriodType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="CanadaAddressType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="AddressType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="LengthAtAddress" type="TimePeriodType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So, the below instance xml

```
<LengthAtAddress unitOfLength="Months">
    <Length>36</Length>
</LengthAtAddress>
```

should be mapped to the following pojo

```
public abstract class AbstractAddress
{
    protected int lengthAtAddress;
    protected UnitOfLengthType unitOfLengthAtAddress;

    public int getLengthAtAddress()
    {
        return lengthAtAddress;
    }

    public UnitOfLengthType getUnitOfLengthAtAddress()
    {
        return unitOfLengthAtAddress;
    }

    //setters
}
```

I think I should be using a combination of **xml-registry** and **xml-element-decl** while using **external mapping**. Not able to figure our how. Any help is appreciated.

**FIX**

```
<xml-element java-attribute="lengthAtAddress" xml-path="LengthAtAddress/Length/text()"/>
    <xml-element java-attribute="unitOfLengthAtAddress" xml-path="LengthAtAddress/@unitOfLength">
    <xml-java-type-adapter value="com.equifax.ic.platform.sts.domain.transformation.response.CommonsEnumAdapter"/>
</xml-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension or the equivalent in MOXy's external mapping document.

```
@XmlPath("LengthAtAddress/Length/text()")
public int getLengthAtAddress()
{
    return lengthAtAddress;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I got it working with xml-path. So is this the only way? I ran xjc on my schema and I see that the compiler is generating a class for "TimePeriodType" and is declaring the property as  "@XmlElement(name = "LengthAtAddress") protected TimePeriodType lengthAtAddress;" in the USAddress class. Can't we emulate the same thing on xml?